# Validate a form using ParselyJS

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I was wondering how to validate a simple form in parsely, this is my basic form email, username, firstname, lastname and password. I have just downloaded parsely and have looked at a few examples but still dont understand

```
<input id='remail' type='text' class='textinput' style="border-radius:5px; color: rgb(170, 170, 170); margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; width: 266px; height: 16px; padding: 6px;" />
<input id='rusername' type='text' class='textinput' style="border-radius:5px; color: rgb(170, 170, 170); margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; width: 266px; height: 16px; padding: 6px;" />
<input id='rfirstname' type='text' class='textinput' style="border-radius:5px; color: rgb(170, 170, 170); margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; width: 266px; height: 16px; padding: 6px;" />
<input id='rlastname' type='text' class='textinput' style="border-radius:5px; color: rgb(170, 170, 170); margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; width: 266px; height: 16px; padding: 6px;" />
<input id='rpassword' type='password' class='textinput' style="border-radius:5px; color: rgb(170, 170, 170); margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; width: 266px; height: 16px; padding: 6px;" />
<input id='rcpassword' type='password' class='textinput' style="border-radius:5px; color: rgb(170, 170, 170); margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; width: 175px; height: 16px; padding: 6px;" />
```

Comment: have u gone through this-> http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html

Comment: please read documentation and search for examples before asking questions like this on stackoverflow -- basic usage of ParselyJS is well covered in its documentation.